# "ReferenceError: command is not defined"

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, referenceerror

**Hello**, I am making a Discord robot on Visual Studio Code.
**I have an error that appears** :

> ReferenceError: command is not defined.

**Here is my code** (Sorry, the robot's answers are in French because I am.),

*I specify that the code I put is only the "help.js"*
**I have another "index.js" file**

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js'),
    config = require('../config.json')

var prefix = ("+");
 
module.exports = {
    run: (message, args, client) => {
            if (args[0]) {
            const command = client.commands.get(args[0].toLowerCase())
            if (!command || !command.help) return message.channel.send('  \' .'), 
             message.channel.send(new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                 .setDescription(`*** : ${command.name}***\n\n${command.help.description}\n\n : \`${config.prefix}${command.name}${command.help.syntax ? ` ${command.help.syntax}` : ''}\``)
                 .setColor('RANDOM'))
        }            
        else if(message.content === prefix + "help"){
            message.channel.send(new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setDescription(" __ __**__Voici toutes les commandes disponible grâce au magnifique Pinocchio.__**")
            .setThumbnail('https://i66.servimg.com/u/f66/20/08/95/81/intero10.png')
            .addField("⛏  Modération :", `${command.name}`)
            .addField(`${client.commands.filter(command => command.help).map(command => `\`${config.prefix}${command.name}\``).join(' ')}\n\n  '   ,  \`${config.prefix}ℎ [nom de la commande]\``)
            .addField("  Utilitaires :", "`poll`, `8ball`, `say`, `embed`,")
            .addField("  Musique :", "`BIENTÔT`")
            .setColor("#728cd9")
            .setTimestamp()
            .setFooter('Develop by Tomatee#0010', 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/853692920737824778/854420356591648778/fifi.jpg+help'))
            }
    },
    name: 'help',
    help: {
        description: '    \'  \'.',
        syntax: '[nom de la commande]'
    }
}
```

**Can you help me?**
[Here is a photo if you want more information file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAQQM.png)

Comment: `const` variables are block-scoped.

Comment: There is a comma after the early return.  Maybe that was supposed to be a semicolon.

Comment: `command` is only defined in the if(args[0]) block, not in the else block where you also use it.